# 'No command land 'P' error message after takeoff using djitellopy

Tags: python, dji-sdk, tello-drone

I have written this very simple code:

```
from djitellopy import Tello
import time
tello=Tello
tello.takeoff() # works just fine!
time.sleep(2)
tello.land() # returns error!
```

If there is any help I would appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 1):

i can see what your error is, on line 3 in your code,

```
from djitellopy import Tello
import time
tello=Tello
tello.takeoff() # works just fine!
time.sleep(2)
tello.land() # returns error!
```

look closely at the `tello=Tello` .. that needs to be `tello=Tello()`, so ur code becomes this:

```
from djitellopy import Tello
import time
tello=Tello()
tello.takeoff() # works just fine!
time.sleep(2)
tello.land() # returns error!
```

and that should work fine! enjoy!